# How do I highlight the words of a subtitle of a video with the corresponding voices?

Tags: video, video-editor, subtitles

I would like to highlight the words of a subtitle of a video with the corresponding voices exactly like this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6sSM5sgR0Ms). How Can I do this?

Comment: Welcome! There are many tools that could be used, so we'll need a little more information to help you out. What is your budget? What is your skill/experience level? What OS do you use?

Comment: @MichaelLiebman  I am looking for a free video editing tool. I have no such experience.  I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and macOS Sierra.